# Why does Java tell me my applet contains both signed and unsigned code?

Tags: java, security, applet, mixed-code

My signed Java applet has been running fine until Java update 19.  Now some but not all of our users on Java Update 19 report a java security message stating that our applet contains both signed and unsigned code.

The process for creating our applet is as follows:

1. Clean and Build the applet project in Netbeans IDE.
2. Open the Applet jar file in WinRAR and add the required mysql JDBC driver .class files to the jar file.
3. Sign the applet jar file.

Can someone please tell me how to determine what code is signed and what code is not signed in our applet?  Is there a better way to include the mysql JDBC driver jar file in our applet other than copying the jar file contents into our applet jar file?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some things to try:

- Go to the java plugin control panel ($JAVA_HOME/bin/ControlPanel).
- Go to the `Advanced` tab.
- Expand `Debug`
- Check `Enable tracing`, `Enable logging`, and `Show applet lifecycle exceptions`
- Expand `Java console`
- Check `Show console`
- Click `OK` (or `Close`, depending on your OS)

When your applet loads the Java console will open. Click on it and immediately press '5'. It will log the jars and classes being fetched to run your applet. Somewhere in this there should be a message indicating what jars or classes are consider "unsigned".  If you miss it the first time, just reload the window to try it again.

Comment: Adding this for future reference. Java 1.6u20 contains a fix documented as "Mixed code warning for class.getResource("directory/") in 1.6.0_19".

Comment: Some where in this there should be a message indicating what jars or classes are consider "unsigned"
What is the message? security: Istrusted: null false ??

Comment: for what it's worth, this problem was there for a machine on 1.6.0_20, then went away with 1.6.0_24, now is back for 1.6.0_25-b06.  What the heck Sun?!  both our jars are signed with the same cert in the same way at the same time, I don't get it...

Comment: @joelarson by Sun you mean Oracle?

Comment: As of 7u21 the mixed code warning is also triggered if the applet interacts with Javascript. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) In this case no warning is shown in the Java console even if level 5 trace is enabled.

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: Due to a bug in Java 7 Update 45 you should not add Trusted-Library to your manifest file. Just add the new attribute Caller-Allowable-Codebase. See this question for more info: [Java applet manifest - Allow all Caller-Allowable-Codebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393826/java-applet-manifest-allow-all-caller-allowable-codebase)

Java 7 Update 21 was released on April 16 2013 and caused our applet to start showing this warning dialog.

Per the release notes:
As of JDK 7u21, JavaScript code that calls code within a privileged applet is treated as mixed code and warning dialogs are raised if the signed JAR files are not tagged with the Trusted-Library attribute.

To fix this edit your manifest.mf file and add a line like this:

```
Trusted-Library: true
```

You should be very careful before doing this though. If your signed applet can be called from javascript then a malicious user can potentially do harmful things on your users' computers.

One quick way to secure your applet is to prevent it from being run on other websites. Do this by putting code in the `init()` method that looks at `getCodeBase().getHost()` and throws an exception if it does not match your site.

Java 7 Update 25 introduces another way to limit the sites where your applet can be run. You can set the Codebase attribute in your manifest file like this:

```
Codebase: test.example.com www.example.com
```

Java 7 Update 45 (releated October 16 2013) introduces more changes to the LiveConnect system (javascript-to-applet bridge) that may cause another prompt. This article talks about the 7u45 changes: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/liveconnect_changes_in_7u45

Basically you'll also want to add the following to your manifest file to avoid the prompts:

```
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: test.example.com www.example.com
```

If you are selling a product that includes an applet and you don't know what domains it can be deployed on you can populate * here.

Comment: If you were selling packaged software that included a signed java applet, does this mean that you would now need to include each and every domain that your applet could run on in the Caller-allowable-codebase segment? In a packaged software environment, you may not even know the domain that your customer is going to be running your applet on?

Comment: Yes, I guess you have to have Caller-Allowable-Codebase in the applet and it must contain those domains. That is crazy. A couple things I can think of to work-around this: Inside the Java applet you can execute javascript and I haven't seen restrictions with that. You can maybe re-work your code so that the JS-Java interactions are initiated from within the applet. The other option is to automate the creation of the applet JAR with the correct domains as part of the installation process.

Comment: @muzzamo I just tried it with * in Caller-Allowable-Codebase and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing trusted and untrusted code together is a vulnerability that has been fixed in the 6u19 (the current CPU/SSR release at the time of writing). [See the docs.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) Blocking the mix or using a debugger should show where the problem is.

Comment: useful: Trusted-Library: true

Comment: @simpatico Useful if you know what you are doing. Exceeding dangerous if you do not.