# A little concerned about Java WEB START

Tags: java, jnlp, usability

I'm completely cool with the Java Plugin being deprecated. Hardly anyone bothers with Applets anymore, and users hate them. But I like Java Web Start or JNLP and many are using them.

BUT

If I download a JNLP file and attempt to run it, I cannot. The JDK on my computer only allows High security or Very high security, not Low or Normal. In fact the only way I can run the file, is to manually type in an exception for the Domain it is signed as; which doesn't immediately work.

My question is:

- Is there a quick runaround for this? I can get the {damn} thing to run for myself, but normal users are never going to pick this up, even if they'd find the configuration in Control panel.

Comment: Your second "question" is a statement

Comment: I know - that's the reason for the disclaimer - it's shot in the dark to see if others have similar feelings - please just disregard if it is inappropriate

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the "inappropriate" parts of your question.  IMO, that is better than asking people to "disregard" them.  If you don't like it, you can revert my edit, but beware that people might then just vote to close your question.

Comment: For the record, I think they are inappropriate because 1) Any discussion of Oracle's support (or lack of) for Java will attract loud and pointless "discusssion" rather than objective answers (there is no >>objective<< answer!). 2) While your "I will never ..." is an interesting comment, it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in that you can add your URL/domain to the trusted site list as a workaround, which is usually not a great solution when distributing to users.

A better solution would be to sign your application. Take a look at this post, which talks in detail about this subject:

[Java 7u51 will not accept JNLP with self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481826/java-7u51-will-not-accept-jnlp-with-self-signed-certificate)