# JNLP file downloaded from http is blocked by Java security from running

Tags: java, jnlp, java-security

I have an application which is deployed on Weblogic server on HTTP protocol only. When I am hitting the application URL then it is downloading a JNLP file like `App-Client.jnlp`. But when I am trying to run the same then Java is blocking the said application from running.

See the below screenshot for the same.

[image: JNLP Application Blocked By Java]

So far I have tried two below things

1. Tried to define a new ruleset in ruleset.xml in the jar file location at `C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment\DeploymentRuleSet.jar` and defined a new rule along with the existing rules like below. But it didn't work.

   `<rule>
       <id location="HTTP://COMPLETE_URL:PORT/PATH" />
       <action permission="run" />
   </rule>`
2. Tried to add the URL with HTTP protocol into the exception list of Java in control panel but it is not even persisting my URL into the exception list as in it adds initially but the moment I press Ok on the exception list dialogue it vanishes.

Has anybody got any idea what to do?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems your JNLP is self.signed, so read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481826/java-7u51-will-not-accept-jnlp-with-self-signed-certificate

Comment: I am not sure if it is self-signed or not but what is the point when I trying to access it using the HTTP protocol. There is no way it should be considering any kind of certificate in the complete process.

Comment: I was reffering to the JNLP app signature, not to SSL . However I think you should insist with point 2. What happens if you try with http://portecle.sourceforge.net/webstart/portecle.jnlp ?

Comment: Behaviour is the same as that of mine! What do you suspect?

Comment: I should insist with point 2 to have the jnlp url in into the exception list. The behaviour of the Java control panel you described, is strange. Maybe you should try with admin privileges.

Comment: Ok. Let me try that with admin rights.

Comment: With the admin rights, it's not even adding; forget about saving it to the list!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211125/discussion-between-stefano-curcio-and-varun-jain).