# Signed applet w/ signed JNLP template produces java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp, signed-applet

I'm signing the JNLP file used by my RIA, in preparation for the coming [tighter security restrictions](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) in `7u51`, due in January.  The webstart version is working great, but I've run into a problem where the applet version fails to launch with the following exception.

Google has apparently never heard of this exception.  :(

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JAR should not contain JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the applet was not being deployed as a JNLP applet.  A security fix was introduced in `7u25` that was intended to prevent the re-purposing of a JNLP applet via the legacy `<applet/>` tag deployment mechanism.  This exception indicates that that security fix has been tripped.

The work-around is either to always deploy your applets as JNLP applets, or to use a different variant of the JAR file that does not contain a `JNLP-INF` directory.

Note that you may also see this variant if you're signing the JNLP itself rather than a template:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JAR should not contain JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP
```