# Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for:

Tags: java, jar, manifest, sign

I have an application with some external jars I created. With the new java policy I had to sign my application and all jars. I buyed a certificate and signed my jar application and all other jars. Then I got a error "`missing permissions attribute in jar manifest`". I added `Permissions: all-permissions` to the manifest of my jar (not the other external jars). And now I have the error `Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for:...` But I don't know what I have to put as application-name. Is that the name of my jar?

I tried to add to the manifest of all other jars "Permissions: all-permissions" but then my application doesn't work at all.

thanks for the answers

Comment: `Application-Name` is the name of your application. Did you sign all of your jars?

Comment: yes I signed all jars. The problem is that I don't know what the name is of my application. I didn't write the application, I just got it from someone else. And now I have to do the maintenant on it. Where can I find the name of the program. Is that the name of the jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what helps me out: 
[How do I fix "missing Codebase, Permissions, and Application-Name manifest attribute" in my JNLP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-fix-missing-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-manifest-attri)

I just had to put THREE extra attributes in the manifest of ALL jars.

Comment: Read article and wanna ask: Could I just edit someone's jnlp file as end-user to prevent these popups?

Also tried to edit `/etc/icedtea-web/javaws.policy` file (with codebase from jnlp) and include this file on javaws run to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I was also getting security warnings similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393826/java-applet-manifest-allow-all-caller-allowable-codebase)

It was a quick fix by making sure then when exporting the jar file I had  "Export Java source files and resources" ticked. Didn't even need to adjust the manifest file in the end.