# Security warning prompt for Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, certificate, warnings, manifest

Starting from JRE 1.7 update 55, in some circumstances (not always, expecially if i call application by host-name instead of by IP), security warning is always shown, even if i check "Don't show this message again".

Manifest is fixed according to the latest directives

**UPDATE**

Investigating JRE security log, i've noticed that, where applet works correctly, i've these lines:

```
security: Caricamento certificati di distribuzione da C:\Users\Redturtle\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Certificati di distribuzione caricati da C:\Users\Redturtle\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Caricamento certificati di distribuzione da C:\Users\Redturtle\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\sandbox.certs
security: Certificati di distribuzione caricati da C:\Users\Redturtle\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\sandbox.certs
security: Caricamento certificati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Certificati caricati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Caricamento certificati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Certificati caricati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Caricamento certificati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Certificati caricati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Caricamento certificati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Certificati caricati dallarea di memorizzazione dei certificati della sessione di distribuzione
security: Caricamento certificati dall'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher
security: Certificati caricati dall'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher
security: Caricamento certificati dall'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer DISALLOWED
security: Certificati caricati dall'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer DISALLOWED
security: Convalidare la catena certificati utilizzando lAPI CertPath
security: Caricamento certificati dall'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer ROOT
security: Certificati caricati dall'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer ROOT
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: C0D522435C73EA3761CD73BA125025E4961B3CAF892E211FCAF5542CA1A83965
security: Controllo della presenza del certificato nell'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer DISALLOWED
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 376377FD1FAF4B8A5B1472647A70B941039A62D74CFE99447E48616F8D63A978
security: Controllo della presenza del certificato nell'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer DISALLOWED
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 7431E5F4C3C1CE4690774F0B61E05440883BA9A01ED00BA6ABD7806ED3B118CF
security: Controllo della presenza del certificato nell'area di memorizzazione dei certificati di Internet Explorer DISALLOWED
```

Where doesn't works, these lines doesn't appears!

Sorry for italian language.